# Using Statement with Stream, StreamReader and WebResponse

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, io, httpwebrequest, using

I have been noticing what seems to be memory leaks in some of my services, and I am trying to make sure that I am handling resources properly. I have the following code used to send an external Http request. I am not sure if I am missing anything, or if there are too many **using** statements.

```
        string str = string.Empty;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(paramBuilder.ToString());
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    str = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    reader.Close();

                    return str;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have "too many" using statements.

Using `using` simply creates a scope for an `IDisposable` resource such that when it leaves that scope, `IDisposable.Dispose()` is invoked.  A good implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose()` should tolerate the object already having been disposed, so extra `Dispose()` calls will not affect proper implementations of the pattern.

Your call to `reader.Close()` is not strictly necessary since the reader will be closed when it is disposed.

I do not see any obvious sources of memory leaks in the posted code.  Try using a memory profiler such as the one included in Visual Studio to isolate the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

You only need curly braces after the last `using` statement.

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return str;
}
```

Otherwise your code looks okay.